# httponly cookie support in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Can anyone confirm if the latest release of Apache httpClient 4.0.1 or 4.1 alpha2  supports httpOnly cookie. (Did not find anything in the release notes but the source code validation for cookies does not raise exception when value is not existing?)

Since the previous versions raise an exception on trying to parse HttpOnly stating that no value was found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no JIRA on it at http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT

May be not implemented since it's not in an RFC yet

Comment: Unfortunately could not find any reference to future goals of implementing this in the library.